# Is "a very heavy security" correct in English?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns

Can I say in English "There is a very heavy security around that building" meaning that there are not only many security guards around the building, but there are also some other security-related measures and devices?

Google didn't return any results for "There is a very heavy security", which makes me think this usage is wrong, but I am no sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Security" is a mass noun, so it should not have an indefinite article: "There is very heavy security."

Comment: Thank you. Can in this case it imply not only the guards, but also some devices?

Comment: "Security" is broad enough that it could mean guards and/or devices. With "around" I would guess the sentence is talking about security outside the building itself, which could include guards, fences, and exterior cameras.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: You can find out whether a word is a mass noun (uncountable noun) by looking in a good dictionary. In the Cambridge Dictionary, uncountable nouns are marked [U}. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/security

Answer (score 2):

Your phrase can't use an article, so use:

> There is very heavy security around that building.

But often you will hear:

> There is **a very heavy security presence** around that building.

where [presence](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/presence) is a singular noun (definition 1).

Though in either case you can't really know what the "security" involves.